# Send multiple kafka messages to same recipient using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am currently having below configuration for Apache camel route

```
from(sourceEndpoint).routeId(sourceEndpoint).unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson).choice().when(criteria)
                    .bean(xyz.class, "processAndSendMessage")
                    //.bean(xyz.class, "processAndSendAnotherMessage")
                    .recipientList(simple(destinationEndpoint));
```

`processAndSendMessage` method uses Exchange to send message with `exchange.getOut().setBody(message);` But I want to send multiple messages to same recipients. I tried to attach another bean method `processAndSendAnotherMessage` (as commented in code above) but it didn't work.

Is there any way to configure that?

Comment: Do you want to send different messages or the same message multiple times? What is the criteria or condition for sending it again?

Comment: Different messages. Criteria is business specific but it’s different json field value that triggers 2 message instead of just 1